# Cannot upload signed apk to play store, but keystore is correct

Tags: android, certificate, keystore

I'm trying to upload an update for my app on play store, i checked the upload Fingerprint SHA-1 on play store and it is the same of my keystore key. But when i try to upload the signed apk, play console says that it is not signed with the upload certificate and shows me that my apk sign sha-1 is different! Any help is appreciated

Comment: That data alone is not enough to find out your problem.

Comment: I dont'know what else say. I checked my keystore's key sha-1 sign and it's the same shown on play store site. I also use both v1 and v2 sign options and i even tried v1 only. I have absolutely no idea what else i can try

Comment: I had the same issue but choosing to sign with both v1 and v2 fixed it for me.

Comment: I tried both but doesn't worked. I just don't understand why my keystore sha-1 is the same asked from play console. but when i sign the apk in release mode and upload it, play store tell me the sha-1 is different